# Java front-end for CSV files held on UNIX server needed

Tags: java, linux, unix, csv, sunos

Thanks for stopping by my question. I am writing to identify the best way to create a particular solution.

BACKGROUND:

I've a UNIX server running SunOS (which I'll refer to as tweetypi), which retrieves statistics (call volumes/response times) from many other servers and stores them as CSV files in the following format (the number don't mean anything in this sample):

```
    Time, Num, <1sec, 1-2s, 2-3s, ... >10s, Avg
    00-01, 43,      ,     ,     ,         ,
    01-02,   ,      ,     ,     ,     11  ,
    02-03,   ,   45 ,     , 45  ,         ,
    03-04,   ,      ,     ,     ,         ,
    04-05,   ,      , 57  ,     ,         ,
    05-06,   ,      ,     ,     ,         ,
    ...      
    23-24, 10,      ,     ,     ,         ,  
    Total, 10,  10  , 12  , 15  ,     1   , 15
```

Having all of the server statistics means we can send them out in an Excel-openable format to partners upon request.

NEEDED:

I need to create a java (because I'm most familiar with it, and already have Java installed on tweetypi) front-end which:

1. Is accessible from a browser/launchable as an application
2. Collates the statistics in the CSV file and outputs them specific information in a graph

QUESTION:

What's the best way to go about this? Browser or app? Best Java libraries? Any other tips? Any potential roadblocks?

NOTE:

I know I could have researched this, but there's always the chance of missing out on a more elegant/better solution. Also, THANKS for taking the time to read this, and even more so for taking the time to answer it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now created this application.

What I did:

Created bat script to execute a WinSCP script
WinSCP script uses private key to passwordlessly log into gateway server and execute script on it
Script SCPs files to central gateway
WinSCP script pulls files to host machine
Java application reads files in folder f 
Java application uses JFreeChart to cycle through data and add to datasets/create graph